# I get 502 and 504 error from nginx in node.js

Tags: node.js

I changed the config file to increase the time and uploading size and doesn't found the php-fsm file. whenever I try to click after some time it stuck and gives 504 error and then 502 error every time.

This is my nginx.conf file.. which is located on etc/nginx/nginx.conf Please give me the solution for this issue as my project is on hold because of these things and i need to launch my web app as soon as possible.

```js
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##

 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 600;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
        
        # set client body size to 500M #
        
       

        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600; 

        
        client_header_timeout 3000;
        client_body_timeout 3000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 800m;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 128k; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;

        #client_max_body_size 800M;
        #client_header_timeout 3000;
        #client_body_timeout 3000;
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
         #client_max_body_size 800m;
        #fastcgi_buffers 8 128k; 
        #fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        #proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        #proxy_send_timeout          600;
        #proxy_read_timeout          600;
        #send_timeout                600; 
 # server_tokens off;

 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 # server_name_in_redirect off;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;

 ##
 # SSL Settings
 ##

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";

 # gzip_vary on;
 # gzip_proxied any;
 # gzip_comp_level 6;
 # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 # gzip_http_version 1.1;
 # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
# # See sample authentication script at:
# # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
# # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
# # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
# # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:110;
#  protocol   pop3;
#  proxy      on;
# }
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:143;
#  protocol   imap;
#  proxy      on;
# }
#}
```